# A way to transfer specific files from a raspberry pi to an app using ssh

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

We want to transfer files from the pi into the app using ssh. We know how to connect to the pi via the app but are confused how the specific files we want are transferred over. We have tried checking discussion boards and online for tutorials but to no prevail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at [scp](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/scp)?

Comment: There are a few ways to transfer files through ssh. Your question is pretty vague.